# How can I do INNER JOIN in Django in legacy database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Sorry for probably simple question but I'm a newby in Django and really confused.

I have an ugly legacy tables that I can not change. 
It has 2 tables:

```
class Salespersons(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    xsin = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Store(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    xsin = models.IntegerField()
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

So I suppose I can not add Foreign keys in class definitions because they change the tables.

I need to execute such sql request:

```
SELECT * FROM Salespersons, Store INNER JOIN Store ON (Salespersons.xsin = Store.xsin);
```

How can I achieve it using Django ORM? 
Or I'm allowed to get Salespersons and Store separately i.e.

```
stores = Store.objects.filter(xsin = 1000)
salespersons = Salespersons.objects.filter(xsin = 1000)
```

Comment: It depends on what exactly are you trying to retrieve. What does `xsin` mean? Does it "point" to a 3rd table?

Comment: xsin is a field by which some tables are joined. Yes, it can be used to join the third table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your example query, are your *tables* actually named Salespersons/Store?
Anyway, something like this should work:

```
results = Salespersons.objects.extra(tables=["Store"],
                          where=["""Salespersons.xsin = Store.xsin"""])
```

**However**, given the names of the tables/models it doesn't seem to me that an inner join would be logically correct. Unless you *always* have just 1 salesperson per store with same `xsin`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make one of the `xsin` fields unique, you can use a ForeignKey with [to_field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) to generate the inner join like this:

```
class Salespersons(models.Model):
    xsin = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class Store(models.Model):
    xsin = models.ForeignKey(Salespersons, db_column='xsin', to_field='xsin')

>>> Store.objects.selected_related('xsin')
```

Comment: Thank you, really valuable. But what if I want to create an another Foreign Key in Store class. This foreign key will point to another table, for example class StoreCredentials(models.Model): xsin = models.IntegerField(unique=True). Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you can't use the `models.ForeignKey` fields even if the database lacks the constraints -- if you don't explicitly execute the SQL to change the database then the tables won't change.  If you use a `ForeignKey` then you can use `Salespersons.objects.select_related('xsin')` to request that the related objects are fetched at the same time.

Comment: Could you provide an example for Foreign Key please?

Comment: class Salespersons(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    xsin = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
If I will do like this, Django will create store_id field if I unserstand it correctly

Comment: Excuse me for this. I mean: store = models.ForeignKey(Customer)

Comment: @gennad: Yes it will create store_id with FK constraint. But why would you name `store` a FK field towards Customer?

Comment: Hm... Sorry, did not understand. How could I achieve is using Foreign Key ? Is there a better way?